# Inject memory to a process using Qt

Tags: qt, memory, code-injection

Well i'm actually working on a Memory Injector. What i'm actually trying to do is to inject memory into a process.

Which class would let me do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QSharedMemory](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qsharedmemory.html#details) is probably what you are after.

Of course I am assuming you are building both the injector and injected processes...